# Unable to shift at high RPM on a motorcycle sequential gearbox

Tags: honda, motorcycle, shifting, sequential-transmission

As the title suggests, I'm unable to shift at high RPM (> 11000 rpm) on a motorcycle sequential gearbox (Honda CBR600RR 2007). There's absolutely no noise or feedback on the pedal.

The issue only occurs from 5th to 6th, wether I use or not the clutch.

At first I though the issue was related with the shift forks and/or gearshift drum, but after opening the engine that doesn't seem to be the case.

Any other hints?

Comment: When you say there is no feedback on the pedal - you feel nothing and the level moves through its normal travel?

Comment: Are you certain you are not already in 6th and trying to change 7th which doesn't exist

Comment: Does this motorcycle have ESP (electronic shift program)? About the era of your bike, Honda was coming out with advanced electronics with sensors for revs, shifting, input shaft speed, etc. Maybe there is a sensor causing an issue, or maybe it is protecting itself. Can you tell us any more details about the bike?

Comment: Does it shift into 6th at low revs with no issues?

Comment: The pedal does not move through its normal travel, its simply "stuck". And I'm sure I'm not already in 6th! Once I reduce the rpms I'm able to engage the next gear successfully.

All gears shift seamlessly at low RPMS (< 10000).

Comment: @MiguelFonseca Does the bike lurch forward on high revs with the clutch pressed (disengaged) ?

Answer (score 1):

If there's nothing really wrong with the gearbox then it's likely that you're just getting false neutrals between 5&6th gear.. Sometimes you can just be a little lazy when shifting up and this initiatives the false neutral.. Sometimes lowering the gear lever one spline can help here as it makes for that little more positive lever selection.